# Getting error when using Mapkit in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

> NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MKMapView)

I am getting this error.Have I missed something?

I don't know from where to add Mapkit framework. First I tried with `target->getInfo` and then from the bottom + sign added framework but that did not work. Then I searched in a spotlight and added another framework. By adding this it removed previous error but gives the above one.

What is the exact location of Mapkit framework? I want to test it in simulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Frameworks (assuming 3.x) are in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 2):

> With Xcode 3.2, MapKit is
>   pre-populated in the Add → Existing
>   Frameworks… dialog and simply requires
>   selecting MapKit from the list.

from http://cs491f09.wordpress.com/2009/10/30/assignment-6-adding-the-mapkit-framework/

Comment: That said, I am able to get this working in the Simulator but then when I try it on the Device it gives me the same 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException' error as above.